# Select element, simple_form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to create an element in my form that uses simple form+bootstrap. The idea is to allow a user select a type of currency from a drop down.

Customer_currency to select from either USD- US Dollars, LRD - Liberian dollar among others.

I have used the following in my form

However, it is not working, all I see is a drop down (out of position) in my form with the options but no label.

How can i create a good select element with a label using simple form

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.select :customer_currency, [['UGX- Uganda Shillings',1],['USD- US Dollars',2]] %>
<%= f.input :payment_terms %>
<%= f.input :billing_address %>
<%= f.input :first_name %>
<%= f.input :last_name %>
<%= f.input :mobile %>
<%= f.input :email %>
<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            customers_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have added it in the question

Comment: For some reason, it is still not displaying the label

Answer (score 10):

```
<%= f.input :customer_currency, :collection => [['UGX- Uganda Shillings',1],['USD- US Dollars',2]] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `label_method` and `value_method` to your select, means change:

```
<%= f.select :customer_currency, [['UGX- Uganda Shillings',1],['USD- US Dollars',2]] %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.select :customer_currency, [['UGX- Uganda Shillings',1],['USD- US Dollars',2]], label_method: :first, value_method: :last %>
```

**Update: other solution**

```
<%= f.input :customer_currency, as: :select, [['UGX- Uganda Shillings',1],['USD- US Dollars',2]], label_method: :first, value_method: :last %>
```

Comment: Hey, the update did not work either, but this one did <%= f.input :customer_currency, :collection => [['UGX- Uganda Shillings',1],['USD- US Dollars',2]] %>